# ¿Cómo sacar todas las cantidades dependiendo del año (o mes, todos los febreros) en un Dataframe en Pandas Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Tengo un Dataframe de la siguiente manera y estructura.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fecha es:

FECHA     non-null   datetime64[ns]

Si quiero sacar todos los números correspondiente a 1 año o a un mes ( todos los eneros independientemente del año), ¿Cómo se realiza?

Estoy intentando hacer un `for` por los años que hay. Es decir, me hago un `set` con los años y luego el `for`. Pero tampoco me sale bien el `for`.

```
for anno in set(matriz2['Fecha'].dt.year):
  anno = pd.DataFrame (matriz2.loc[matriz2['Fecha'].dt.year == anno])
```

Comment: ¿ Cómo has intentado implementarlo ?

Comment: con un for del set de los años. Te lo muestro en pregunta mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mejor cuando estás trabajando con un conjunto de datos temporales en `Pandas` es **poner la fecha, como índice, esto te facilitará mucho el trabajo**, ya que mediante el índice podrás hacer selecciones de fecha de forma sencilla. Te dejo un Ejemplo explicado en el código:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Creo un DataFrame de ejemplo
df_shop = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4000,4), columns=["ventas", "publicidad","coste","beneficio"])
#Creo un rango de tiempo acorde al DataFrame creado
df_shop['date'] = pd.date_range("1-1-2010", periods=4000)

#Paso los datos temporales, de columna a índice
df_shop.index = df_shop['date']
#Borro la columna de tiempo ya que la tengo en el índice
df_shop = df_shop.drop(columns=['date'])

#Mediante el índice, le digo que selecciones solo los meses 1.
df_shop[df_shop.index.month==1]
```

Por supuesto se pueden hacer varios tipos de selecciones, puedes **seleccionar por año**:

```
#Mediante el índice, selecciono solo el año 2010.
df_shop[df_shop.index.year==2010]
```

**Seleccionar por día:**

```
#Mediante el índice, selecciono todos los días 31
df_shop[df_shop.index.day==31]
```

Si nuestros datos estuvieran en horas, minutos o segundos, se podría hacer el mismo procedimiento. Todo esto y más lo puedes encontrar en la [documentación oficial de Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) sobre uso de datos temporales.

**Como conclusión** casi nunca es buena idea usar bucles `for` con DataFrames de `Pandas`, ya que esta biblioteca ha sido creada con muchas funciones cuya intención es esa, evitar los bucles `for` y parecerse más a el manejo que tendrías en `SQL`. Por lo que cuando pienses en hacer iteraciones, seguramente `Pandas` tenga métodos/funciónes **que hagan lo que quieres y de forma más sencilla.**

Comment: Muchas gracias. No ya por la ayuda. Si no por la leccion. Muchas gracias. me pongo a ello y te haré caso. Al menos voy a intentarlo. Me parece mucho mejor que todo lo que se me estaba ocurriendo a mi. Más sencillo de implementar y más "limpio"

Comment: De nada @DANIEL siempre es un gusto ayudar :) Si te ha servido mis respuesta, la mejor forma de dar las gracias en StackOverflow es aceptando la respuesta en el tick  "aceptar respuesta",  y ¿Por qué no? ¡Darle también un voto positivo! Esto no solo me recomenpensara a mí por la ayuda, si no que hará que la pregunta perdure en el tiempo y le pueda ser de ayuda a personas con el mismo problema que tú en el futuro! Te recomiendo leer [Vota pronto, vota con frecuencia](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2209/vota-pronto-vota-con-frecuencia)